# Checking whether the result is positive definite or positive semi-definite with two methods

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given, $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1  & 1\\ 
 1&1  & 1\\ 
 1&  1& 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I want to see if the matrix $A$ positive (negative)  (semi-) definite.

Using **Method 1:**

Define the quadratic form as $Q(x)=x'Ax$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, with $x \neq 0$.

So, $Q(x)=x'Ax = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} &x_{2}  &x_{3} 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1  & 1\\ 
 1&1  & 1\\ 
 1&  1& 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\x_{2} 
\\x_{3} 
\end{bmatrix}$.

After multiplying out the matrices I am left with $$Q(x) = x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}+2(x_{1}x_{2} + x_{1}x_{3}+x_{2}x_{3}).$$

So by Method 1, I get that $A$ is **positive definite**.

Using **Method 2:**

I calculate all principle minors $A$ and if they're all positive, then the matrix is positive definite (learned recently from @hermes).

So $|A_{1}| =1> 0$, $|A_{2}| = 0$, and $|A_{3}| = |A| = 0$.

So $A$ is **positive semi-definite**.

Which method am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix is actually positive semi-definite. All your calculations are correct; only the conclusion in **Method 1** is incorrect.

Note that for **Method 1**, you got
$$Q(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+2(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2\ge0$$
with equality whenever $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$.

For a solid example, you can take $x=(-1,0,1)$ to get $Q(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

First is wrong. $Q(x)$ doesn't mean $A$ is positive definite.

Moreover $rank(A)=1$. Since $A$ is not of full rank, it can not be positive definite.

Answer (score 2):

What about a **Method 3)**? Your matrix has rank $1$ and its eigenvalues are $3,0,0$. Since it is a symmetric matrix, it is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Didn't know about the method but good point. Could you please elaborate on Method 3 a bit. Like a step-by-step procedure on how to would implement it for this problem.

Comment: @OGC: well, that is a rank-$1$ matrix, hence two eigenvalues are zero. $(1,1,1)^T$ is an eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda=3$. By the spectral theorem, your matrix is conjugated (through an orthogonal transformation) with a diagonal matrix having $3,0,0$ as diagonal elements, hence your matrix is positive semi-definite since the last matrix is.